# xmake always reports: error: cannot get program for cxx, why?

Tags: lua, g++, xmake, c++

I've "brew install xmake" on my mac, and having a .cpp file, I run xmake and it generates a xmake.lua in the directory. Then it reports:

```
error: cannot get program for cxx
```

I've installed clang (alias as g++). It works fine. I then:

```
$sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++ /usr/local/bin/cxx
```

Well, running xmake again, but it still reports same error:

```
error: cannot get program for cxx
```

How to handle this? Thanks

----------------------I tried these, don't work:

```
$xmake f -p cross

$xmake
error: cannot get program for cxx

$export CC=clang LD=clang++ xmake
$xmake
error: cannot get program for cxx
```

----------------------See my diagnotics:

```
$xmake f -p cross -c

(In fact no output)

$xmake -r -v
configure
{
    plat = cross
,   arch = none
,   ccache = true
,   kind = static
,   buildir = build
,   host = macosx
,   mode = release
,   clean = true
}

checking for the g++ ... no
checking for the linker (ld: g++) ... no
checking for the gcc ... no
checking for the linker (ld: gcc) ... no
checking for the clang++ ... no
checking for the linker (ld: clang++) ... no
checking for the clang ... no
checking for the linker (ld: clang) ... no
error: cannot get program for ld

$which g++
/usr/bin/g++

$which clang
/usr/bin/clang
```

Comment: I'm not sure `cxx` is an appropriate tag for this question, as currently no other questions are tagged with it.

Answer (score 2):

xmake will detect and use `xcrun -sdk macosx clang` on macOS. Do you have Xcode command line tools installed?

If not, you can switch to cross platform to compile it. for example

```
xmake f -p cross
xmake
```

It will use gcc/clang directly.

Or set `--cc=clang` or CC, LD envirnoment vars to modify compiler and linker.

```
xmake f -c --cc=clang --ld=clang++
xmake
```

Or

export CC=clang LD=clang++
xmake

Comment: I don't have Xcode command line installed. But the 3 methods below do not work :(

Comment: Please run `xmake f -p cross -c; xmake -r -v` and give me the output info. I need see more verbose log.

Comment: xmake will try to run `clang --version` to detect clang/gcc, but it seems that the test failed.  You can try run `clang --version` and `g++ --version`  manually to confirm that it works.

Comment: In addition, you can run `xmake l lib.detect.find_tool clang` to detect clang or gcc directly. And let me see the output info.

Answer (score 1):

It works now, please update to latest version.